# Get pdf file content in Itext

Tags: java, itext

Is there a way i can get the content of a pdf file ("example.pdf") into an IText object like Paragraph or a Chunk?

I need to use the content in a new pdf i am generating (among other text).

Comment: You say you need to use the content in a new pdf you are generating. How dynamic is your use? Do you re-use complete pages? Or do you really need to reflow stuff? In the former case, use a PdfStamper which is meant to manipulate existing PDFs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, at least not easily.

When iText puts Chunks and Paragraphs and all such objects into a PDF (or other PDF creating programs their respective objects), the information of "the words from here to there form a paragraph" or "these words form a chapter" is generally lost. Instead all there remains are multiple positioned letter groups. (Ok, there can be more information, but mostly there isn't.)

What you can do, though, is parse the content of a PDF using the classes e.g. in the iText parser package to retrieve those positioned letter groups and apply some heuristics to them to guess which of them form a paragraph, or a chapter, or whatever.

Answer (score 0):

its C# code, but should work on java too.
Namespace `iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;` on java it looks a bit defferent, but it must be `.parse`

```
Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(48.031496063f, 643.307086614f, 198.42519685f + 68.031496063f, 70.866141732f + 663.307086614f);
RenderFilter f = new RegionTextRenderFilter(rect);
List<RenderFilter> fi = new List<RenderFilter>();
fi.Add(f); 
ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), fi.ToArray()); 
//on java it should be:  ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new FilteredTextRenderListener(new LocationTextExtractionStrategy(), f); 
sw.WriteLine(PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(reader, 1, strategy));
```

object `rect` is area which you would like to OCR. All text should be put into txt file very similar as it i shown on pdf. For more information about OCR on iText you should check chapter 15.3 in "iText in action. 2nd edition" by Bruno Lowagie.

Disclaimer. I have nothing to do with Bruno, just reading his book. It answered a lot of my questions how to use iText(Sharp).